# Is it possible to detect a scroll on the parent from within an iframe?

Tags: iframe, css

We just need to know that a scroll has taken place in our iframe.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not get slapped with cross-site restrictions, then yes.

Otherwise, no. (At least not without elaborate mutually-supported workarounds.)